# NHibernate Criteria Query - Select Distinct with Joined Entity

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, icriteria

I have a Person entity.  Every person has a country, I want to select all the distinct countries that have people in them. This Criteria Query returns all the distinct CountryID's

```
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("Country")));
```

How do I alter it to join and fetch the Country entity, not just the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any easy way would be to use a subquery. That is, you could select the whole country on the outer query where the country ID matches the inner query.

```
Subqueries.PropertyIn(
  "Country",
  innerDetachedCriteriaWhichFindsCountriesWithPeopleAndProjectsCountryId)
```

Comment: This would work but I don't have a detached Criteria, so I either need a way to convert an ICriteria into a DetachedCriteria or I can't use this.  This constructor looks promising, but I have no idea what to pass in for CriteriaImpl DetachedCriteria(NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl, NHibernate.ICriteria)

Comment: You can go the other way, actually. Build your criteria using only DetachedCriteria instances (DetachedCriteria.For<T>()), then use GetExecutableCriteria(session) to convert it to a real, executable criteria.

Comment: This worked, but I had to spend hours changing all my ICriteria objects to DetachedCriteria objects, and then attach them to a session when I need them.  Any other way would have introduced duplication and I've been stung before by bugs where I updated one thing and not the other.  Let me know if anyone knows how to do it with an ICriteria rather than a DetachedCriteria