# Hibernate criteria distinct with join - fetch the relation

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I've searched on the internet but I didn't understand very much the problem:

I'm trying to build a distinct query using criteria and a distinct clause using a projection, trying to resole the lazy attribute of the projection in the distinct.

So the query will be like this

Code:

> createCriteria(Parent.class)
>   .setProject(Projections.distinct(Projections.properties("relation")))
>   .createCriteria("relation")

Unfortunately, the relation fields aren't fetched, this query return just a list of id's and I have to generate O(n) queries for fetching the results.

The equivalent in HQL would be

Code:

> select distinct r from Parent as p
>   join p.relation as r

Is it possible to do it using criteria?

I've seen that someone suggest to use the trasnformer, but I would like to use the distinct in the database.

Thank you very much.

Possible duplicate for [NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753161/nhibernate-criteria-query-select-distinct-with-joined-entity)?